# How to print the result of calling a Rust function in rust-gdb?

Tags: rust, gdb

I want to print a function's result in the rust-gdb console.

fn.rs

```
fn one() -> i32 {
    1
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", one());
}
```

console

```
rustc -g ./fn.rs
rust-gdb ./fn
>>> b 6
>>> run
>>> print one()
Invalid data type for function to be called.
```

Are there any means to display the function result?

I am using Rust 1.27.0 and GDB 7.11. I am compiling fn.rs directly; there is no module. I tried these additional commands:

```
(gdb) p one 
$1 = 1 
(gdb) p one() 
Invalid data type for function to be called. 
(gdb) p 
::module::one() A syntax error in expression, near ::one()'. 
(gdb) p 
::module::one A syntax error in expression, near ::one'. 
(gdb) p 
fn::one() No symbol "one" in namespace "fn".
```

p one() is disable?

Comment: Did you compile in release mode?

Comment: @Boiethios `rustc -g ./fn.rs`

Comment: You are in a module `fn`: did you try to print the definition with the full path (*i.e.* `fn::one()`)? Display the list of the functions if you're not sure about the path.

Comment: It might help to have more information about the platform you are running and version of `rustc` and `rust-gdb`. When I run exactly what you posted, `gdb` does display `$1 = 1` as expected.

Comment: @mcarton Did you try it with the function in another module?

Comment: Wrapping in a module also works: `print ::module::one()` also results in `$1 = 1`.

Comment: @Boiethios there's no module here. OP is directly compiling the file `fn.rs`

Comment: Thanks everyone, I use rustc==1.27.0 and gdb==7.11
I use fn.rs only. There is no module.
I tried additional command.

    (gdb) p one
    $1 = 1
    (gdb) p one()
    Invalid data type for function to be called.
    (gdb) p ::module::one()
    A syntax error in expression, near `::one()'.
    (gdb) p ::module::one
    A syntax error in expression, near `::one'.
    (gdb) p fn::one()
    No symbol "one" in namespace "fn". 

@mcarton Thanks, which version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried gdb==8.11.
It works perfect.

```
(gdb) p one
$1 = {fn () -> i32} 0x55555555a5a0 <fn::one>
(gdb) p one()
$2 = 1
```

Thanks, everyone. (especially @mcarton)